# No bass on my laptop

Tags: 12.04, sound, pulseaudio, alsa

A have a laptop (Acer) with two front speakers and subwoffer (Acer Tuba). After upgrading to 12.04 only front speakers are working, no sound from subwoffer. There is no 2.1 configuration on Sound configuration panel, only 2.0 4.0, 4.1, 5.0, 5.1, but no matter what I choose a can't get sound from subwoofer. Sound is very poor quality without bass speaker. Sound card is Realtek ALC888.

Comment: related http://askubuntu.com/questions/891566/laptop-only-using-subwoofer-rather-then-surround-sound?noredirect=1#comment1397013_891566

Comment: After searching on the internet and spending a ton of time trying to figure out an issue just like this one, it appears like this is a bug rather then a configuration issue, if you agree with this assessment can you please confirm (/state that it also affects you) on here https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pulseaudio/+bug/1672822