# Laptop only using subwoofer rather then surround sound

Tags: drivers, sound, pulseaudio, alsa, acer

I have a (still relatively new) acer predator laptop (G9-593-7757 15,6"/i7-7700/32 GB RAM/512 GB SSD/1 TB HDD/GTX1070) running 16.10 and noticed that the sound sounds far more hollow then when I use windows. It appears as if the laptop is only using the subwoofer rather then the 2 other speakers making the sound distorted.

Here is my `/etc/pulse/deamon.etc` file

```
# This file is part of PulseAudio.
#
# PulseAudio is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
# it under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as published by
# the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License, or
# (at your option) any later version.
#
# PulseAudio is distributed in the hope that it will be useful, but
# WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
# MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE. See the GNU
# General Public License for more details.
#
# You should have received a copy of the GNU Lesser General Public License
# along with PulseAudio; if not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.

## Configuration file for the PulseAudio daemon. See pulse-daemon.conf(5) for
## more information. Default values are commented out.  Use either ; or # for
## commenting.

; daemonize = no
; fail = yes
; allow-module-loading = yes
; allow-exit = yes
; use-pid-file = yes
; system-instance = no
; local-server-type = user
; enable-shm = yes
; shm-size-bytes = 0 # setting this 0 will use the system-default, usually 64 MiB
; lock-memory = no
; cpu-limit = no

; high-priority = yes
; nice-level = -11

; realtime-scheduling = yes
; realtime-priority = 5

; exit-idle-time = 20
; scache-idle-time = 20

; dl-search-path = (depends on architecture)

; load-default-script-file = yes
; default-script-file = /etc/pulse/default.pa

; log-target = auto
; log-level = notice
; log-meta = no
; log-time = no
; log-backtrace = 0

; resample-method = speex-float-1
; enable-remixing = yes
; enable-lfe-remixing = no
; lfe-crossover-freq = 0

flat-volumes = no

; rlimit-fsize = -1
; rlimit-data = -1
; rlimit-stack = -1
; rlimit-core = -1
; rlimit-as = -1
; rlimit-rss = -1
; rlimit-nproc = -1
; rlimit-nofile = 256
; rlimit-memlock = -1
; rlimit-locks = -1
; rlimit-sigpending = -1
; rlimit-msgqueue = -1
; rlimit-nice = 31
; rlimit-rtprio = 9
; rlimit-rttime = 200000

; default-sample-format = s16le
; default-sample-rate = 44100
; alternate-sample-rate = 48000
; default-sample-channels = 2
; default-channel-map = front-left,front-right

; default-fragments = 4
; default-fragment-size-msec = 25

; enable-deferred-volume = yes
deferred-volume-safety-margin-usec = 1
; deferred-volume-extra-delay-usec = 0
```

here are my devices

```
$ cat /proc/asound/devices 
  1:        : sequencer
  2: [ 0]   : control
  3: [ 0- 0]: digital audio playback
  4: [ 0- 0]: digital audio capture
  5: [ 0- 0]: hardware dependent
 33:        : timer

$ cat /proc/asound/cards
 0 [PCH            ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH
                      HDA Intel PCH at 0x83620000 irq 134
```

Anybody got any ideas?

Comment: Please try this solution : un-comment and change the settings of `; default-sample-channels = 2` | `; default-channel-map = front-left,front-right` | `; enable-lfe-remixing = no` ... so that it reads : `default-sample-channels = 3` | `default-channel-map = front-left,front-right,lfe` | `enable-lfe-remixing = yes`. Then reboot the system - please report  back whether it solves the problem and in case that it works, I could write an answer. Good luck ! :)

Comment: OK it looks like this problem might be caused by a bug, if you also suffer from this can you please report so here https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pulseaudio/+bug/1672822