# high cpu usage and regular crashes from pulseadio in 17.04

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, 17.04

I have an acer predator laptop (G9-593-7757 15,6"/i7-7700/32 GB RAM/512 GB SSD/1 TB HDD/GTX1070 with ubuntu 17.04 and every few hours my system crashes especially often when I'm doing things like playing youtube videos. It also appears that pulseaudio is using about 10-20% cpu which given that this is a high end device sounds like a lot. So I think they are related.

It appears that close to the crash I get the following log from /var/log/syslog

```
Jun 30 16:48:25 AI-restored gnome-session[2290]: gnome-session-binary[2290]: GLib-GObject-CRITICAL: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
Jun 30 16:48:25 AI-restored gnome-session[2290]: gnome-session-binary[2290]: GLib-GObject-CRITICAL: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
Jun 30 16:48:25 AI-restored indicator-sound[1718]: volume-control-pulse.vala:735: unable to get pulse unix socket: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.PulseAudio1 was not provided by any .service files .
```

It might also be related too [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/891566/laptop-only-using-subwoofer-rather-then-surround-sound) problem which is still not solved and is also related to the audio on my system.

Anybody know what is wrong with it and/or how to fix this?

Comment: If you think there is any other log I should add please ask, I just didn't want to put in every log that I have.